# accessing an array of objects from an object in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these functions:

```
getPermissions: function(){
        return currentUser.permissions;
       }, //It returns permissions which is an array of strings as well.I use it in resolve first, before loading the page and it works

hasRole: function(){
        console.log(currentUser);
      return currentUser.role; //role is an array of objects but gives undefined
       }
```

`currentUser` is an object that looks like this:

[image: currentUser]

`currentUser.role` gives undefined probably because promise has not been resolved yet. I have to  redirect the user just after login on basis of value contained in currentUser.role. How do I ? first resolve and then redirect? I think it really should solve the problem.

EDIT: I have above mentioned functions in a file called `auth.js`. `auth.js` has login function as well that looks like this:

```
 login: function(user, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post('/auth/local', {
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password
        }).
        success(function(data) {
          $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
          currentUser = User.get();
          deferred.resolve(data);
          return cb();
        }).
        error(function(err) {
          this.logout();
          deferred.reject(err);
          return cb(err);
        }.bind(this));

        return deferred.promise;
      }
```

I am calling login function from `auth.js` in `login.controller.js`.

```
  $scope.submitted = true;

      if(form.$valid) {
        Auth.login({
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password
        })
        .then( function() {
          // Logged in, redirect to home
        var role = Auth.hasRole();
        console.log("role");
        console.log(role);  //gives undefined
       if(role.priority >= 1){
          $location.path('/admincontrol');

        }else{
          $location.path('/');

        }

        })
        .catch( function(err) {
          $scope.errors.other = err.message;
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: Yes, It gives can not read property 0 of undefined.

Comment: Could you add where and how you initialize the "currentUser" var ?

Comment: Are you sure, that `currentUser` initialized *before* you're trying to get access to `role`. Chrome lists object only after you're expanding it. Please provide part of  code, which should initilalize `currentUser`

Comment: @Andrey: Could you please check the update ?

Comment: @SimranKaur: And what `User.get()` returns? I can only guess that this is a promise.